# String comparison with a don't care (ignore) character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have two lists, a `golden` strings list and a `measured` strings list. I have to compare these lists element by element.

The strings have exactly the same length. There are characters in the golden strings which are marked with `'X'`, and these should not considered in the comparison.

For example:

```
Golden = [
    '023XX1FD', 'FEBFF1B6', 'XXXXXXXX', '????????', '00000XXX', 
    '00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000800'
]

Measured = [
    '0236C1FD', 'FEBFF1B6', '00F1FC3F', '????????', '00000000', 
    '00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000800'
]
```

and comparison of `'023XX1FD'` with `'0236C1FD'` should return true since we should only be comparing the parts that are not equal to `'X'` in the golden string.

For this example, the output is `True` for every string.

Comment: So what's your desired output?

Comment: I compare the two lists item by item and for each comparison I have to get a true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[all(char1 == 'X' or char1 == char2 for char1, char2 in zip(str1, str2)) for str1, str2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own string comparison function to go through the characters one by one and compare them, as long as the golden character is not the "Don't Care" value:

```
def myStringCompare(golden, measured, dont_care="X"):
    return (
        (len(golden) == len(measured)) and 
        all(g == m for g, m in zip(golden, measured) if g != dont_care)
    )
```

Then use this function in a list comprehension:

```
print([myStringCompare(a, b) for a, b in zip(Golden, Measured)])
#[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to come up with the following list comprehension:

```
result_list = [
    all(
        [
            symbol == b[list_index][symbol_index]
            for symbol_index, symbol in enumerate(item)
            if symbol != "X"
        ]
    )
    for list_index, item in enumerate(a)
]


> [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```